# How to make predictions using XGBoost

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to make my first model using XGBoost and I cannot figure out how to actually get my prediction values. I was able to train a model and get root means squared error values, but I don't know where to go from here.

My dataset is about house prices. I am using variables such as: LotFrontage, LotArea, BldgType, OverallQual, OverallCond, FullBath, HalfBath, TotRmsAbvGrd, YearBuilt, TotalBsmtSF, BedroomAbvGr, and GrLivArea. Some of these variables are numeric and some are strings.

Here is my code and where I am getting an error:

```
library(data.table)
library(caret)
library(Metrics)
library(xgboost)

train<-fread("train_data.csv")
test<-fread("test_data.csv")

sub_train<-train[,.(LotFrontage,LotArea,BldgType,OverallQual,OverallCond,FullBath,HalfBath,TotRmsAbvGrd,YearBuilt,TotalBsmtSF,BedroomAbvGr,GrLivArea,SalePrice)]
sub_test<-test[,.(LotFrontage,LotArea,BldgType,OverallQual,OverallCond,FullBath,HalfBath,TotRmsAbvGrd,YearBuilt,TotalBsmtSF,BedroomAbvGr,GrLivArea)]

sub_test$SalePrice<-0

y.train<-sub_train$SalePrice
y.test<-sub_test$SalePrice

dummies <- dummyVars(SalePrice~ ., data = sub_train)
x.train<-predict(dummies, newdata = sub_train)
x.test<-predict(dummies, newdata = sub_test)

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(x.train,label=y.train,missing=NA)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(x.test,label=y.test,missing=NA)


param <- list(  objective           = "reg:linear",
            gamma               =0.02,
            booster             = "gbtree",
            eval_metric         = "rmse",
            eta                 = 0.02,
            max_depth           = 10,
            subsample           = 0.9,
            colsample_bytree    = 0.9,
            tree_method = 'hist'
```

)

```
XGBm<-xgb.cv( params=param,nfold=5,nrounds=2000,missing=NA,data=dtrain,print_every_n=1)
pred<-predict(XGBm, sub_test$SalePrice)



watchlist <- list(eval = dtest, train = dtrain)
XGBm<-xgb.train( params=param,nrounds=200,missing=NA,data=dtrain,watchlist,early_stop_round=20,print_every_n=1)
sub_train2 <- xgb.DMatrix(x.train,label=y.train,missing=NA)
pred1<-predict(XGBm, sub_train$SalePrice)
```

Here is a screenshot of my error:[image]

So, I would like to get a csv file full of predicted house prices. I want to update the SalePrice column within the train dataset or the sub_train dataset like `sub_train$SalePrice<-predict(XGBoost,sub_train$SalePrice)`. Any ideas?

Also, I have gotten a "predict" line to run, but it just gives me decimals like .823 and .174 and so on, and that is not what I am looking for. I want house prices with values over 100,000.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to predict sale prices, what you probably need to try is `pred <- predict(XGBm, sub_test)`